# trying to save django form data after submit to a thankyou page with details

Tags: python, html, django

If I add redirect url in form submit page, the page is redirecting but the form data is not being saved to db. If I remove the redirect url, form data is getting saved but my redirect doesn't work. I need to redirect to a page with the details of the event along with a thank you message.

Please let me know where I am going wrong..

#forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = webinar_user
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email_id', 'contact_no', 'city', 
        'state','postal_code','country','company']
```

#views.py

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = "site/new_form.html"
    event = get_object_or_404(webinar_event, slug=slug)
    # event = get_object_or_404(webinar_event, pk=post_id)
    # success_url = "events:thankyou"
    user_data= None
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        print("form")
        if user_form.is_valid():
            print("form valid")
            user_data= user_form.save(commit=False)
            user_data.event= event
            req= user_data.save()

            subject = 'Thank You for registering for the webinar'
            context={'first_name':user_data.first_name, 'title':event.title, 
            'description':event.about_event, 'event_date':event.event_date, 
            'event_time':event.event_time, 'event_duration':event.event_duration}

            message = get_template('site/emails/thank_you.html').render(context)
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            email_id = user_form.cleaned_data['email_id']
            recipient_list = [email_id, ]
            email = EmailMessage(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
            email.content_subtype = 'html'
            email.send()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('events:thank_you', kwargs={'id':req.id})
)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(
        request,
        template_name,
        {
            "event": event,
            "user_data":user_data,
            "user_form": user_form
        },
    )

def thank_you(request, id):

    event = webinar_event.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'site/thankyou.html',
                              {'event' : event})
```

## html code

```
<div class="testbox">
     {% if event.event_image %}
     <img src={{event.event_image.url}}>
     {% endif %}
      <form action="{% url 'events:thank_you' event.id%}" method= "post">

          {% csrf_token %}

          <div class="banner">
          <h1>{{event.title}}</h1>
              <br>
              <hr>
              <h2>{{event.event_date}}</h2>
<!--            <img src={{event.image.url}}>-->

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpResponseRedirect` class doesn't do URL resolution.

You can either do

```
url = resolve_url('events:thank_you', kwargs={'id':req.id}))
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

or preferably

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# ...
return redirect('events:thank_you', id=req.id)
```

... and in the future, save yourself effort by using the `CreateView` base class instead of hand-coding form views :)

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. My problem is more or less saving the form data. If I change this action="{% url 'events:thank_you' event.id%}" to action="", the form data is getting saved, but in thank you page I am not able to get the event information. If I keep the action url, the form data is not getting saved to db but redirection with event details on thank you page are working..

Comment: You pass the `webinar_user`'s id to the thank you page and are trying to get a `webinar_event` with that same id...

Comment: Oh.. I thought i was passing id of the webinar event.. Coz I was able to get data on the thank you page

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing the action url in the form and calling kwargs={'id':event.id}) and changing the return to  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('events:thank_you', kwargs={'id':event.id})).